# Load YouTube JSON API dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, json, youtube, youtube-api

I want to dynamically make different YouTube JSON API requests and then use a function to sort the data I want.

Currently following the examples on the YouTube data JSON API site [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html).

Here is my current code which is getting me the id's nicely.
My question is currently it's using a script tag and the callback URL query to use my function. Is there a different way that I can implement in JavaScript only and keep doing requests that call my `getid` function?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getid(data) {
    var i=0;
    for(items in data.data){
        i++
         console.log(data.data.items[i].id)  
    }
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=getid"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonp` function below will dynamically create a script tag and append it to the body.

```
function jsonp(url,callback) {                    
  var script = document.createElement("script");        
  script.setAttribute("src",url);
  script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");                
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function getid(data) {
  var i=0;

  for(items in data.data){
    i++
    console.log(data.data.items[i].id)  
  }
}

// pass a url and callback
var url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=getid";  
jsonp(url, getid)
```